# Can't Add IBAction Button in Container View

Tags: ios, uiview, parent-child, ibaction

In my app, I have a view controller that contains container views embedded in a view. The container views are stacked on top of each other and hidden to start.

```
viewDidLoad 

self.containerOne.hidden = YES
self.containerTwo.hidden = YES
```

I'd like to add an IBAction button to the first container view, that when touched, unhides the second container view. I can't seem to be able to add a IBAction connection from that button to the .h file. As if I'm not allowed to do that. Am I doing something wrong is this just not allowed? If it's not allowed, how do you suggest I create a parent view that has multiple child views that I can reveal one at a time? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe UIContainerViews have actions associated with them. I haven't tested this, but you should try something where you add tapGestureRecognizers to the views and hide them depending on which action is fired:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *firstTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(containerOneTapped)];
    firstTap.cancelsTouchesInView=NO;
    [self.containerOne addGestureRecognizer:firstTap];
    [firstTap release];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *secondTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(containerTwoTapped)];
    secondTap.cancelsTouchesInView=NO;
    [self.containerTwo addGestureRecognizer:secondTap];
    [secondTap release];    
}

-(void)containerOneTapped
{
    self.containerTwo.hidden=NO;
}

-(void)containerTwoTapped
{
    self.containerOne.hidden=NO;
}
```